# Creating an environment in LaTeX

Tags: environments, boxes

I would like to create a custom environment that lets me write text into a gray box. Basically this:

```
\begin{center}
\noindent\fcolorbox{black}{gray!30}{%
    \parbox{33em}{%
        \vspace{15pt}
         text
        \vspace{15pt}
    }%
}
\end{center}
```

but with just one `\begin` and `\end` statement.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. With just one `\begin` and `\end` statement? What should that mean? `\begin{foo}...\end{foo}`? I think `mdframed`, `tcolorbox` and other packages can do this 'out-of-the-box' (pun intended!)

Comment: Yes. Just \begin{mybox} text inside the box \end{mybox} for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here an example using `mdframed`, showing some of the numerous options to configure such a box environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\newmdenv[linecolor=black, leftmargin=2em,rightmargin=2em,innertopmargin=2em,innerbottommargin=2em]{infobox}

\begin{infobox}[backgroundcolor={lightgray}]
foo foo foo
\end{infobox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can create your own environment using

```
\newenvironment{name}{begin code}{end code}
```

and then use it as

```
\begin{name}
...
\end{name}
```

This does not work in your case, since it is not possible to split pairs of braces and put the opening one into `begin code` and the closing one into `end code`. In such cases the package `environ` helps with its `\NewEnviron`. It puts everything between `\begin{name}` and `\end{name}` into `\BODY`, which then can be used in the code defining the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{graybox}%
  {\begin{center}%
   \noindent\fcolorbox{black}{gray!30}%
     {\parbox{33em}%
       {\vspace{15pt}\par
        \BODY
        \vspace{15pt}\par
       }%
     }%
   \end{center}%
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{graybox}
text
\end{graybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{%
  %
  enhanced jigsaw,
  width=33em, % Width of the box
  boxsep=0pt, % No extra spacing
  top=15pt, % top spacing
  bottom=15pt, % bottom spacing
  sharp corners,
  colframe={black},
  colback={gray!30},
  #1
}
\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
  And now for something completely different
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}[colback=green, colframe=blue,boxrule=2pt]
  And now for something completely different and nicer!
\end{mybox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that green would definitely look at home on a tropical beetle.

Comment: Well the 'nicer' is definitely arguable.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I want to provoke ;-)

Comment: @Skillmon: Ok, lets argue....

Comment: First: It does produce eye-cancer imho :) And the green is way too shiny to concentrate on the text.

Comment: @Skillmon: Green is a nice colour. period!